# Appending multiple rows in df2 to df1 based on datetime

Tags: python, append, concatenation

I have 2 data frames, df1 and df2, both have the same format.

For example, df1 looks like this:

```
      Date  A   B   C   D   E
2018-03-01  1  40  30  30  70
2018-03-02  3  60  70  50  55
2018-03-03  4  60  70  45  80
2018-03-04  5  80  90  30  47
2018-03-05  3  40  40  37  20
```

df2 *may* look like this: The only difference is the start date

```
      Date  A   B   C   D   E
2018-03-03  4  60  70  45  80
2018-03-04  5  80  90  30  47
2018-03-05  3  40  40  37  20
2018-03-06  7  55  26  46  42
2018-03-07  2  73  46  33  25
```

I want to append all the rows from df2 to df1, in this case, all the rows from 2018-03-06 so that df1 becomes:

```
      Date  A   B   C   D   E
2018-03-01  1  40  30  30  70
2018-03-02  3  60  70  50  55
2018-03-03  4  60  70  45  80
2018-03-04  5  80  90  30  47
2018-03-05  3  40  40  37  20
2018-03-06  7  55  26  46  42
2018-03-07  2  73  46  33  25
```

**Note**: df2 may skip 2018-03-06, so all rows from 2018-03-07 will be copied and appended if that's the case.

My dtype for df['Date'] is datetime64. I got an error when I tried to index the last_date of df1 to find the next_date to copy from df2.

```
>>>> last_date = df1['Date'].tail(1)
>>>> next_date = datetime.datetime(last_date) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

Alternatively, how would you copy all the rows in df2 (starting from the date after the last date of df1) and append them to df1? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
Use `combine_first` on the `Date` column:

```
i = df1.set_index('Date')
j = df2[df2.Date.gt(df1.Date.max())].set_index('Date')

i.combine_first(j).reset_index()

         Date    A     B     C     D     E
0  2018-03-01  1.0  40.0  30.0  30.0  70.0
1  2018-03-02  3.0  60.0  70.0  50.0  55.0
2  2018-03-03  4.0  60.0  70.0  45.0  80.0
3  2018-03-04  5.0  80.0  90.0  30.0  47.0
4  2018-03-05  3.0  40.0  40.0  37.0  20.0
5  2018-03-06  7.0  55.0  26.0  46.0  42.0
6  2018-03-07  2.0  73.0  46.0  33.0  25.0
```

---

**Option 2**
`concat` + `groupby`

```
pd.concat([i, j]).groupby('Date').first().reset_index()

         Date  A   B   C   D   E
0  2018-03-01  1  40  30  30  70
1  2018-03-02  3  60  70  50  55
2  2018-03-03  4  60  70  45  80
3  2018-03-04  5  80  90  30  47
4  2018-03-05  3  40  40  37  20
5  2018-03-06  7  55  26  46  42
6  2018-03-07  2  73  46  33  25
```

Comment: Thank you so much! They both work, the only difference is that `combine_first` would change the dtype of a column from int64 to float64